# Javascript Increment And Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to swap the class so the output of increments is no longer hidden, and also only have increment by 1 when the checkbox is selected.

```
input[type=text] {width:20px;background:none;border:0px;text-align:center;padding-    left:3px;}
p {font-weight:bold;}
hr {margin:40px 0px;}
.hiddenclass {display:none;}
.class {display:initial;}

if (document.getElementById('return').checked) {
document.getElementById("pcount").className = "class";
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="return" value="Returned" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
<hr>
<p class="hiddenclass" id="pcount">
<input type="text" id="number" value="0" /></p>
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Dfprp/430/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="return" value="Returned" onchange="f();" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
<hr>
<p class="hiddenclass" id="pcount">
  <input type="text" id="number" value="0" />
</p>
<script>
  function f() {
    if (document.getElementById('return').checked) {
      console.log('sdf');
      document.getElementById("pcount").className = '';
      document.getElementById("pcount").className = "class";
      var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      document.getElementById('number').value = value;

    }
  }
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZD6WEXM2SQbtyh11EiXj?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I only just swapped the checkbox action to the submit button `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="f();"/>`

Comment: @Jaz It would be very kind of you to accept this answer, as I am getting negative reputation.